# Printing Ruby value, not address

Tags: ruby, printing

I just started working with Ruby classes and am writing a binary tree class. However, when I go to print the value of a particular node, it prints the hexadecimal memory address as opposed to the actual value. I looked around on the web quite a bit but all I see is puts and print, which are what I am trying. How do you print the actual value and not the address?

```
class Node
attr_accessor :value,:left,:right
def initialize(newValue)
    @value  = newValue
    @left   = nil
    @right  = nil
end

# In my binary tree class after a value has been inserted into the tree....

current_node = @root 

puts current_node.value
```

When I run the output I get BinaryTree::NumericTreeItem:0x007fa101125eb8

Thank you for your time and I apologize for the trivial question. I'm sure it's a simple fix. Haven't been able to find anything else online.

Comment: What does `puts @root.class` say?

Comment: It says BinaryTree::Node

Comment: Can you post a complete code sample that demonstrates the problem?  Trim it down to the smallest amount of code possible that we can run and still get the same output you're seeing.

Comment: Could you give an example of `the expected outcome`?

Comment: It looks like you have assigned a `NumericTreeItem` to your value.  Could you show that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` instance variable in your `Node` contains an instance of a class called `NumericTreeItem`. You don't show what that class is in your question, but let's pretend for a moment that is is defined like so:

```
class NumericTreeItem
  attr_accessor :numericValue

  def initialize(newValue)
    @numericValue = newValue
  end
end
```

Then to print the value in the node:

```
puts current_node.value.numericValue
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the [`to_s` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-to_s) in a class to control what gets printed out in situations like this. I'll borrow the example from the previous answer:

```
class NumericTreeItem
  attr_accessor :numericValue

  def initialize(newValue)
    @numericValue = newValue
  end

  def to_s
    "NumericTreeItem with value of #{@numericValue}"
  end
end
```

Now when you do this line:

```
puts current_node.value
```

you would see something like:

```
NumericTreeItem with value of 5
```

be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. :)